R: calculating AUC for party::cforest
I have binary outcome and multiple covariates. I would like to calculate the AUC for fitted forest( I am using party::cforest to fit random forest). The most confusing part for me is how to split into training and test sets since party::cforest is already using out-of-bag data to test the forest.
Right now I have come with the following code, could you please let me know what I am doing wrong (I am using iris dataset as an example):
library(caret)
library(party)
library(pROC)
set.seed(142)  # Set seed for reproducibility

iris$Species <- iris$Species %>%
     fct_collapse("virginica" = c("virginica", "versicolor"))
splitIndex <- createDataPartition(
  iris$Species, p = .75, list = FALSE, times = 1)

train_set <- iris[ splitIndex,]
test_set  <- iris[-splitIndex,]

crf <- party::cforest(Species ~ ., data = train_set, 
                      control = cforest_unbiased(mtry =2, ntree = 1500))
pred_prob <- predict(crf, newdata = test_set, type = "prob",OOB = TRUE)
second_elements <- lapply(pred_prob, function(x) x[[2]])
roc <- roc(test_set$Species, as.numeric(second_elements))
plot(roc)
auc <- round(auc(roc), digits = 3)
auc

UPD updated the code based on @StephanKolassa comments
And should I at all split the data into test/train? I.e should the code instead be
library(caret)
library(party)
library(pROC)
set.seed(142)  # Set seed for reproducibility

iris$Species <- iris$Species %>%
     fct_collapse("virginica" = c("virginica", "versicolor"))

crf <- party::cforest(Species ~ ., data = iris, 
                      control = cforest_unbiased(mtry =2, ntree = 1500))
pred_prob <- predict(crf, type = "prob",OOB = TRUE)
second_elements <- lapply(pred_prob, function(x) x[[2]])
roc <- roc(iris$Species, as.numeric(second_elements))
plot(roc)
auc <- round(auc(roc), digits = 3)
auc


Please add library commands so your code runs in plain vanilla R. (It breaks on your tidyverse operator %>%.) That said, you would split training and testing data before training your model on the training subset only (and your model might further subdivide this data, as cforest does, or not). The important part is that your model should never see the test data before you actually use it to test.

Finally, note that to calculate an AUC, you actually need a curve, i.e., a parameterized precision-recall trajectory. Usually, this is done by calculating probabilistic predictions (for which you need type="prob"), then varying a threshold. For each threshold, you would compare the predicted probability to the threshold, classify, and calculate precision and recall. Then plot the curve against the threshold. Finally, calculate the area under that curve.

@StephanKolassa updated the code based on your comments

@StephanKolassa the AUC depends on the seed and split of train/test sets though
